# IntoIterator as a function argument doesn't accept adapter struct

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to have a function, that accepts `&IntoIterator<Item=u32>`, so I could pass to it both `&Vec<u32>` and iterators' adapter structs (like `Map`, `Filter` and any other, which I believe all implement `IntoIterator`)

So I have a function like

```
pub fn f<'a, T>(it_src: &'a T) -> u32
where &'a T: IntoIterator<Item = u32> {
    let it = it_src.into_iter();
    let result: u32;
    // more more usage
    result
}
```

And this is how I tried to use it (same signature, but different name)

```
pub fn f_with_feature()<'a, T>(it_src: &'a T) -> u32
where &'a T: IntoIterator<Item = u32> {
    let adjusted_values = it_src.into_iter()
        .map(|e| adjust(e));
    f(&adjusted_values)
}
```

What I've got is an error

```
 error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:14:7
   |
14 |     f(&adjusted_values)
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `std::iter::Map`
   |
   = note: expected type `&T`
              found type `&std::iter::Map<<&T as std::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter, [closure@src\main.rs:13:14: 13:27]>`
```

How is it that Map doesn't match as T?

Also, I've come up with an idea, that passing iterators' adaptors with static dispatch isn't a good idea since each other closure used to generate a Map will create a new function specialization. Though I've seen that static dispatch approach for most of the times is idiomatic in Rust. How to manage this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to have trait bounds on `T` (and not on `&'a T`). So I guess you actually want the following:

```
pub fn f<'a, T>(it_src: &'a T) -> u32
where T: IntoIterator<Item = u32> {
    let it = it_src.into_iter();
    let result: u32 = 1;
    // more more usage
    result
}

pub fn f_with_feature<'a, T>(it_src: &'a T) -> u32
where T: IntoIterator<Item = u32> {
    let adjusted_values = it_src.into_iter()
        .map(|e| adjust(e));
    f(&adjusted_values)
}
```

Which brings us to the next problem: `IntoIterator`'s `into_iter` consumes `self`, which means that you cannot call `it_src.into_iter` if you only borrow `it_src`.

So if you really want to use `into_iter`, you can try this:

```
pub fn f<T>(it_src: T) -> u32
where T: IntoIterator<Item = u32> {
    let it = it_src.into_iter();
    let result: u32 = 1;
    // more more usage
    result
}

pub fn f_with_feature<T>(it_src: T) -> u32
where T: IntoIterator<Item = u32> {
    let adjusted_values = it_src.into_iter()
        .map(|e| adjust(e));
    f(adjusted_values)
}
```

The above, however, requires you to move the values into `f` resp. `f_with_feature`.

In my experience, just taking an iterator (and doing the conversion at call site if necessary), leads to simple, straightforward solutions:

```
pub fn f<T>(it_src: T) -> u32
where T: Iterator<Item = u32> {
    let it = it_src.into_iter();
    let result: u32 = 1;
    // more more usage
    result
}

pub fn f_with_feature<T>(it_src: T) -> u32
where T: Iterator<Item = u32> {
    let adjusted_values = it_src.into_iter()
        .map(|e| adjust(e));
    f(adjusted_values)
}
```

Comment: I've moved to the Iterator approach, but it's sad to force passing an iterator, instead of &Vec<_> which implements IntoIterator and doesn't consume the vector

Comment: `iter()` doesn't consume or copy the vector either.